# Struggling with PUT request

Tags: reactjs

I'm on React for 2 months, and still struggling with CRUD operations such as EDIT.

I've been trying couple different ways, but every time I send nothing to my API.

I do not manage to grab the information correctly in order to push it to the server.

The route is working with Postman, there are no issues there, it's only React and me ^^.

I would be grateful if someone could read my code and tell me where the problem might come from, thanks !

**1st try**

```
const usernamelEl = React.useRef(null)
const timezoneEl = React.useRef(null)

 const handleEditProfile = async () => {

    const creds = {
      user: {
        username: usernameEl.current.value,
        timezone: timezoneEl.current.value
      }
    };

    const config = {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${Cookies.get('token')}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(creds)
    };
    
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/users/${id}`, config);
    const user = await res.json();
    console.log(user)
  }


return (
  <form onSubmit={handleEditProfile} className="form">
    <div className="input-group">
      <label htmlFor="username">username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" ref={usernameEl}/>
     </div>
     <div className="input-group">
       <label htmlFor="timezone">timezone</label>
       <input type="text" id="timezone" ref={timezoneEl}/>
      </div>
      <div className="input-group">
      <SubmitButtonComponent type="submit">
        Submit
      </SubmitButtonComponent>
    </div>
  </form>
)
```

**2nd try**

```
const [usernameEl, setUsernameEl] = useState('')
  const [timezoneEl, setTimezoneEl] = useState('')

  const handleChangeUsername = e => {
    setUsernameEl(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleChangeTimezone= e => {
    setTimezoneEl(e.target.value)
  }


const handleEditProfile = async (e) => {

    const creds = {
      user: {
        username: usernameEl,
        timezone: timezoneEl
    }
    };

    const config = {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${Cookies.get('token')}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(creds)
    };

    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/users/${id}`, config);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)

    try {
      setUsernameEl('')
      setTimezoneEl('')
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }


return (
  <form className="form" onSubmit={handleEditProfile}>
    <div className="input-group">
      <label htmlFor="username">username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" onChange={handleChangeUsername}/>
    </div>
    <div className="input-group">
      <label htmlFor="timezone">timezone</label>
      <input type="text" id="timezone" onChange={handleChangeTimezone}/>
    </div>
    <SubmitButtonComponent type="submit">
      Submit
     </SubmitButtonComponent>
   </form>
```

[image]

**if I ever try to pass a value**

```
const handleEditProfile = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
[..]

onSubmit={(e)=>handleEditProfile(e.target.value)}>
or 
onSubmit={handleEditProfile(e)>
```

**then I get this error**

[image]

Comment: Where is your `id` coming from?